# Customizing Camera View after a button in collection view is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, custom-controls, camera-view

I would like to customize my camera view like the screenshot instead of the default one.

http://imgur.com/QNoto5F

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Read the UIImagePickerController [Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/).
See **cameraOverlayView** and **showsCameraControls** properties.
You can hide the controls, provide a custom overlay view, and add subviews to this custom view to add custom buttons, frames, etc.

If you need more control and more customisation have look at [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/) Also here is the [sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112) from apple .